# Open a method body in the split screen immediately (without having to go thru tab's header)?

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

Is there a way to set Settings or a shortcut which will open a specific method directly into Split screen of IntelliJ or AndroidStudio?

Right now, I am doing the long way via tab's header and choosing one of two split options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your favorite shortcut to split screen.

Go to *Settings -> Keymap*.

Then search for the command split (you can use the search field).

Finally select the command, right click and *"Add keyboard shortcut"*

[image]

Comment: But this still does not open a body of some method in the split screen, right? It will only "split" screen?!

Comment: @sandalone it works for me. Just click the shortcut inside a class or method, and it opens the same class in split mode.

Comment: Yes class, but method? Can I put the caret on `foo()` method in `myObject.foo()` and get its body in the new split screen?

Comment: Just click the shortcut in a line of the method.